# Get all single words from array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm trying to separate and push all words of one array into another array.

Old array:

```
["black cat", "white dog", "grey mouse"]
```

Expected array:

```
["black"],["cat"],["white"],["dog"],["grey"],["mouse"]
```

With my code I still get my 3 arrays separated by a comma:

```
var arr = ["black cat", "white dog", "grey mouse"];
var arr_new = [];

for (i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
   curr_val = arr[i].split(" ");
   arr_new.push(curr_val);
}
```

Comment: Do you want `[["black"],["cat"],["white"],["dog"],["grey"],["mouse"]]` or `["black","cat","white","dog","grey","mouse"]`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because the method `split` return an array with the words split with an space. The solution is iterate over this new array instead of insert (push) in the array.

```
var arr = ["black cat", "white dog", "grey mouse"];
var arr_new = [];

for (i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
   curr_val = arr[i].split(" ");
   for(j=0; j<curr_val.length;j++){
      arr_new.push(curr_val[j]);
   }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This is how I would do it:

```js
var oldArr = ["black cat", "white dog", "grey mouse"];

var newArr = oldArr
  
  // this will turn each string into an Array of Arrays, like this:
  // [["black", "cat"], ["white", "dog"], ["grey", "mouse"]]
  .map(function(item) {
    return item.split(" ");
  })

  // then, flatten this Array of Arrays into a single-level Array.
  // see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce#Flatten_an_array_of_arrays
  .reduce(function(a, b) {
    return a.concat(b);
  }, []);

document.writeln(JSON.stringify(newArr))
```

Answer (score 1):

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/6hLazr5w/1/

```
var newArray=[],
    oldArray = ["black cat", "white dog", "grey mouse"];

for(item in oldArray) {
  tmpArray = oldArray[item].split(' ');
  for(tmp in tmpArray) {
    newArray.push(tmpArray[tmp]);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

here's an option with reduce & replace methods,

```js
var a = ["black cat", "white dog", "grey mouse"] 

var re = a.reduce((acc,x)=>{
  x.replace(/[a-zA-z]+/g,function(m){
    acc.push([m])
  });
  return acc;


},[])

console.log(re)
```